# understanding multiprovider and streams

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I think I couldnt understand the multiproviders in flutter, how it works.

I want to share two version of `MyTabs` class, you can see them in the following.
The problem in the second version is that the stream is being listened to only when the Third tab is selected but  I do not need to do that in the first version of `MyTabs` class, it automatically listens to the stream without selecting the Third Tab.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class StreamData {
  final StreamController<int> _valueStreamController = StreamController<int>();
  late Stream<int> valueStream;

  int _counter = 0;

  Stream<int> get myStream => _valueStreamController.stream;

  int get streamCount => _counter;

  StreamData() {
    valueStream = _valueStreamController.stream;
    _startTimer();
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _counter++;
      _valueStreamController.add(_counter);
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _valueStreamController.close();
  }
}
```

First Version

```dart
class MyTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  MyTabs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<int> myStream = StreamData().myStream;

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<int>(
            create: (context) => myStream,
            initialData: 0,
          ),
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Tab Demo'),
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(text: 'First'),
                Tab(text: 'Second'),
                Tab(text: 'Third'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstScreen(),
              SecondScreen(),
              ThirdScreen(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second Version

```dart
class MyTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  MyTabs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<int>(
            create: (context) => StreamData().myStream,
            initialData: 0,
          ),
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Tab Demo'),
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(text: 'First'),
                Tab(text: 'Second'),
                Tab(text: 'Third'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstScreen(),
              SecondScreen(),
              ThirdScreen(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I couldnt figure out multiproviders and streams in flutter how they works.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem is about the fact that the create function of the StreamProvider is only called when the widget that consumes the stream is built because of that the stream data is not listening immediately when the app runs.

```
  StreamProvider<int>(
    // Provide the stream using StreamProvider
    create: (context) => StreamData().myStream,
    initialData: 0,
  ),
```

If you want to ensure that the stream is created with a specific initial state as soon as the app starts, you might consider creating the stream instance explicitly when the app starts and providing it to the StreamProvider using the .value constructor. This way, the stream instance is ready and available for consumption regardless of when the consuming widget is built.

```
  StreamProvider<int>.value(
      value: StreamData().myStream, initialData: 0)
],
```